# Why is it called "non-type" template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, non-type

In the C++ template terminology we have non-type template parameters, type template parameters, and template template parameters (and then the same list with arguments).

Why is it called *non-type*? Isn't it a *value*? Shouldn't it be "value template parameter"?

Do I miss anything if I think of them as value template parameters?

Note: out of curiosity, I checked the documentation of the D language, and they call it value.

Comment: They could be references. I wouldn't regard those as values, but you'd need a more pedantic language-lawyer than me to determine whether or not one should.

Comment: I'd have to dig up my copy of the ARM, bur IIRC type template parameters were introduced first, non-type parameters second, then template template arguments, and finally now variadic templates. If we'd designed this all from the start, we might have named it better.

Comment: I'm not a C++ programmer at all, I used to love it back in college but those were the very old days.  My only comment here is to show some respect to the C++ community for having to deal with a standard that is ever so growing and just talking about the language seems quite complex to me.  I don't know how you guys do it...but you do..so +1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"value" has a very specific non-intuitive definition in C++ that does not necessarily apply to non-type template arguments:

> **3.9 Types [basic.types]**
>
> 4 The *object representation* of an object of type `T` is the sequence of *N* `unsigned char` objects taken up by the object of type `T`, where *N* equals `sizeof(T)`. The *value representation* of an object is the set of bits that hold the value of type `T`. **For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a *value*, which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values.**

Even though the C++ standard does occasionally use the word "value" informally, it's good that they haven't done so here. A non-type template argument type does not need to be trivially copyable. Specifically, as Mike Seymour commented on the question, it could be a reference type.

That said, I do feel I should note that I don't think the term "non-type template parameter" is a correct one. It used to be, but we now have template template parameters, which aren't types, but also aren't non-type template parameters.

Comment: It seems to be talking about *value representation* which I cannot really figure out: is it the bit pattern within an object instance representation which discriminates it from any other object instance (from the same class or another)?

Comment: @didierc To be honest, I don't know if I'm reading it entirely correctly, but it seems to me that the *value representation* is effectively those bits in the *object representation* that contribute to the value (i.e. those bits that aren't padding).

Answer (score 4):

I am not part of the committee, but I would say the reason is that while you could easily describe arguments for non-type template parameters of type `int` or even `const char *` as a value, it gets less clear for a non-type template parameter of reference type, e.g. `std::string &`. The argument for that parameter is an object, not its value.

Comment: What's the value of a reference? A would say it's the object. Is it wrong to think in those terms? (and is this turtles all the way down?:)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath "What's the value of a reference? A would say it's the object. Is it wrong to think in those terms?" if that works for you, I don't see any harm in it, but would documenting your terminological perspective in the C++ Standard, and explaining and defending it to the C++ community, be more or less confusing and time-consuming for others than saying "Non-Type"?

Comment: I will continue to use non-type ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will be more clear if to consider standard class `std::array` It is declared the following way

```
template <class T, size_t N >
struct array;
```

As it is seen it has two template parameters: type parameter T and non-type parameter N. Why is N a non-type parameter? Because its type is already defined and is equal to `size_t`. For this non-type parameter `N` you have to supply some constant value. For example

```
std::array<int, 10> aq1;
std::array<double, 20> a2;
```

`T` is a type parameter because we have to supply a type as a template argument that to instantiate an object of this class. We may not supply a value as for example

```
std::array<10, 10> a3;
```

though 10 is integer literal of type int. But we may write

```
std::array<decltype( 10 ), 10> a4;
```

Compare the first template argument setting and the second template argument setting.

Comment: I know what a non-type template parameter is. I don't see how this answers my question.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath It looks at least strange. If you know then why are you asking?! My answer clear demonstartes the difference between a type parameter and a non-type parameter.